# What does "fast eye" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases

The following is taken from the subtitles (grammatical errors appear in the film) in the 1979 movie *Wise Blood*:

> Hazel Motes: I only follered her to say I wasn't beholden to none of her *fast eye*
>   like she give me back there.
>
> Preacher's Daughter: What do you mean? I never looked at you with no *fast eye*. I only 
>   watched you tearin' up that tract.

Since she seems offended, my first thought was that "fast eye" means "looking at with physical attraction."

[This dialog is also in the book.](http://books.google.com/books?id=HCfdra7VxNQC&lpg=PA46&ots=EoxpbyfGvr&dq=%22wise%20blood%22%20%22fast%20eye%22&pg=PA46#v=onepage&q=%22wise%20blood%22%20%22fast%20eye%22&f=false)

Comment: This question could be improved by showing what you found in the dictionary or other reference work before you posted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The meaning is most likely from this definition of [*fast*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fast):

> a : wild
>   b : sexually promiscuous

From [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fast#Adjective):

> Having an extravagant lifestyle or immoral habits [from 18th c.]

And from [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=fast&allowed_in_frame=0):

> The sense of "living an unrestrained life" (usually of women) is from 1746 (fast living is from 1745).

Without delving too far into literary criticism, the preacher's daughter, Sabbath Lily, is often the victim of men in the novel and is later revealed to be a nymphomaniac. So this sense of the word is undoubtedly what was implied.

Answer (score 0):

The Fast Eye is when a woman looks at a man and lets him know he can have sex with her with just a look.