# You have a quick eye

Tags: idioms

You have a quick eye. Why didn't you marry her? it's from 'the Age of Innocence'.What is the meaning of 'a quick eye'?

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/81519/what-does-fast-eye-mean

Comment: I searched online and didn't find this quote anywhere. The [only two instances](https://www.google.com/search?num=20&ei=R51EW4O1CoTY_wTK0YeYDA&q=%22You+have+a+quick+eye.+Why+didn%27t+you+marry+her%3F%22&oq=%22You+have+a+quick+eye.+Why+didn%27t+you+marry+her%3F%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...20152.22882.0.23198.2.2.0.0.0.0.233.451.2-2.2.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.2UOKi9uUpoY) reported by Google is your question.

Comment: Thank you Mari-Lou A for your time. " Someone with a "quick eye" spots things swiftly, they are observant"- That's what I received from the other user-now I understand the meaning of the clause. Sorry If am inconsistent-still I can't guess why...

Comment: I didn't say *you* were inconsistent. The comment was beneath @ibf's answer, it was addressed to that user. A user who has posted comments telling different users to show their research, but forgot to do so here. I am also bit confused as to why there are no references that support the quote, and yet the novel is well-known. Did you hear this line in the movie version? Are you 100% sure you heard correctly?

Comment: That's right- it is in the movie version and I heard it correctly. the movie versions of quotes very often confuse me.

Comment: Could you find the clip where those lines were said, and post a link? Can you say "who" said those lines?

Comment: Mrs Mingott (May Welland's grandma) said to Archer Newland. Sorry,  I can't send you a clip

Comment: found text - google book - added to my answer

Answer (score 2):

Someone with a "quick eye" spots things swiftly, they are observant.

Answer (score 1):

more complete text:  [google books](https://books.google.com/books?id=3PcYAAAAYAAJ&lpg=PA153&ots=yKAY4DI-IY&dq=Mrs.%20Mingott%3F%20I%20wasn't%20made%20for%20long%20engagements.%22%20Old%20Catherine%20beamed%20on%20him%20approvingly.%20%22No%3B%20I%20can%20see%20that.%20You've%20got%20a%20quick%20eye.&pg=PA153#v=onepage&q=Mrs.%20Mingott?%20I%20wasn't%20made%20for%20long%20engagements.%22%20Old%20Catherine%20beamed%20on%20him%20approvingly.%20%22No;%20I%20can%20see%20that.%20You've%20got%20a%20quick%20eye.&f=false)

> The young man's heart grew chill, and he said hurriedly: "Can't I
>   persuade you to use your influence with the Wellands, Mrs. Mingott? I
>   wasn't made for long engagements." Old Catherine beamed on him
>   approvingly. "No; I can see that. You've got a **quick eye**. When you
>   were a little boy I've no doubt you liked to be helped first."

**quick-eyed**  [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/quick-eyed)

adj

> ```
> Having a quick or lively eye; sharp-eyed, keen-sighted, perceptive.
> ```

Comment: Weirdly, you're inconsistent about telling users to include their research.

Comment: @Mari-LouA yup, sometimes I feel like a voice crying in the wilderness.

Comment: @Mari-LouA  found text ... added to my answer

Answer (score 0):

having a quick eye means having the ability to perceive or understand.